# Smallest $5$-digit common multiple ($\operatorname{lcm}$) of $32, 36$ and $40$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question:

> What is the smallest $5$-digit common multiple of $32, 36$ and $40$?

My method:

1. $\operatorname{lcm}$ of the given numbers is taken.
2. $\operatorname{lcm}$ in first step divides the least $5$-digit number $10000$.

How should I proceed further?

Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take the lcm of the three numbers, this will give you 1440. Then divide $10000$ by this number $10000/14400=6.94$. So the smallest five-digit number that is divided by the three numbers is the result of the previous division (rounded to the next integer) times the lcm. $7 \cdot 1440 = 10080$.